# Updating passwords in Active directory from Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to update password in Active Directory where SSL is not enabled from a Java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible until you will have at least 128-bit connection. That is with TLS or SSL connection. You can use LDAPS to have secure connection, for example from here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ssl.html

Or you can just setup SSL checking this tutorial:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2012/05/15/how-to-set-active-directory-password-from-java-application.aspx

Comment: Thank you @m.aibin. I was trying out with both SSL and non SSL AD's. And it appears to be from Java, any password operations can be only via SSL/TLS connections.